# How to disable running Hyper-V on windows 10?

Tags: android, android-studio

The Android studio does not allow launch of virtual device until I disable Hyper-V. I tried to disable it by running command - *bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off* & reboot following that. It did not help unfortunately. Is there any stop-gap approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try it, with privilege mode of PowerShell

Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All